# Thermally insulating peltier cell

Tags: thermal, peltier, cooling

I'm trying to build a small cloud chamber using peltier cells. I've been using a TEC2 25408 and a cooler master 412S. So far I've tried to measure the lowest temperature the peltier can reach by placing it on the top of the fan cooler using thermal paste. With this setup I was able to obtain a temperature of about -29.4°C on the cold side of the peltier cell (which is acceptable, I think, since, to make the isopropyl alchool reach the superaturate state, there are required at least -25°C). To make the base of the cloud chamber, I've then tried to place on the cold side of the peltier a 100mm x 100mm x 2mm copper plate, using thermal paste. Since I increased the mass, I was expecting that it would have been cooled down much more slowly, and I was also expecting that the temperature reached could have been higher than -25°C: the reached temperature was about -12°C, indeed, measured directly above the peltier.

To me the problem seems to be that the peltier is not properly thermally insulated. Hence, I thought that it would be useful to insert the peltier inside a layer of polystyrene so that the cooling power concentrates on the copper plate. But I'm not sure this configuration works. Moreover closing the chamber with a plexiglass block limits the mass of air with which the peltier thermally interacts, so this should help lowering the temperature.

I wanted to ask, is the thermal insulation the actual problem? And in that case, have you got any ideas on how to properly insulate the peltier such that plate could reach at least -25°C not only in the center but almost on each point?

P.S. Thanks a lot in advance for any eventual answer and excuse my english, as I'm still learning it!

[image]
on top there is the copper plate, then the peltier, then the fan

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a thermodynamics problem, not an electrical engineering one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is that when you add the copper plate, not just the thermal mass is increased, but also the surface area increases, and hence the thermal resistance decreases. Effectively the copper plate is acting as a radiator.

If you're building a cloud chamber, then presumably you'll be putting this in glass so you'll get some insulation from that. You could also insulate the bottom of the copper in order to only radiate from the useful side.

As for getting -25 *C across the plate, you could make it a bit thicker, and thus it would be more thermally conductive and the temperature across it would be more closely matched, but for the most part, I think you might need to increase the power of your Peltier. The cooling on the hot side of the Peltier is also a limiting factor, so you could see a benefit if you increased this.